# How do symmetries of nature give rise to the conservation laws?

Tags: conservation-laws

In my physics textbook, the following points are given:-

1. The Law of Conservation of linear momentum emerges from the homogenecity of space.
2. Isotropy of Space gives rise to the Law of Conservation of angular momentum.
3. Homogenity of time gives rise to the Law of Conservation of Energy.

However, no explanation for the above three points has been given in my book.Can someone provide explanation for the above 3 points? (If possible, please include mathematics in your explanation.)

Comment: See [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem)

Comment: Thanks. I am a high school student. I had never heard about Neother's theorem earlier. My question has been answered. Please close this question.

Comment: @MrigankaParasar: if you would like to close this question you can click the *close* option and choose to close the question as a duplicate.